# Apache using all cpu and cause OOM killer

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, php, ssh, httpd.conf

I have an Xen-VPS CentOS 6.5 64 Bit with 2GB memory and 4 GB Ram, I have application with php, in my application lot of pages need to image which generated by php_imagick extension, here is apache setting:

```
Timeout 60
KeepAlive Off

MaxKeepAliveRequests 100
KeepAliveTimeout 15

StartServers       8
MinSpareServers    5
MaxSpareServers   20
ServerLimit      256
MaxClients       256
MaxRequestsPerChild  4000

<IfModule worker.c>
StartServers         4
MaxClients         300
MinSpareThreads     25
MaxSpareThreads     75 
ThreadsPerChild     25
MaxRequestsPerChild  0
```

Probleam is that my cpu uses is more, but ram is not using why?
 here is screen shot of cpu use
[top of vps for cpu uses](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3NPfu.jpg)
and here is Ram uses
[free and ram used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S8NjL.jpg)
beacause of cpu uses I encounter OOM, my server is out of  responce randomly, is their any probleam in apache setting ? Server is goes down when I have more then 500 ugers at the time.

Comment: where is the proof that oom is responsible ?

Comment: simply if i have traffic less than 500 its goes smoothly. I really new in vps, is their any cause to server goes down because of high traffic and more cpu use ? help me.

Comment: ok so you guessed. Look in your logs for relevant information.

Comment: If you are not getting any logs, you can also disable oom killer, disable all panic options and then console into the VM to see the stack trace.  Your site will be offline until you correct the situation of course.  You could also disable overcommit, or set the ratio to 0 to that ideally apache dies and not the OS.  Sometimes a panic will happen faster than anything is logged.  You can also extend the panic timers.